# Delete files not needed anymore because of upgrade

Tags: inno-setup

When building a new version of my application, it's possible that files that were needed in a previous version are no longer needed. I would like these to be cleaned up during an upgrade. My ideas so far:

- I considered using the `InstallDelete`, but this would require the current build to know what files the previous build contained. The build process is automated, and I'd prefer that the build didn't have to check in anything. (It makes tagging and the like rather messy.)
- I also considered running an uninstall, but this would mean that the upgrade could not be fully rolled back (since the application would have been uninstalled).

Is there a way to detect files that were present in the old install but not the new one during the install and to have Inno delete them in a way that could be rolled back (or that happens only if the install was successful)?

Comment: Ideally, you should read the last uninstaller's list of files that were installed and compare it with those you are installing by the current upgrade. The difference in those file lists you'd backup somewhere (with a list of those backup files), so you'd be able to restore them when uninstalling. But, reading the uninstaller data file will be quite difficult... You could check that file difference against the app. directory content, but it's quite weak.

Comment: @TLama Yeah. If I understand what you're suggesting in terms of a file difference, that would delete any files the user happened to drop in the app directory that weren't from the the installer. (Not very likely in my case, but I like to follow best practices when I can.) So the only place that file list is stored is in the uninstaller?

Comment: Yup. That's the only place. But you can of course start making another list of the just installed files. That would make your task relatively simple.

Comment: @TLama Sounds like at the moment, the answer is, "Inno Setup doesn't really support this out of the box." Ah, well. Can't have everything. Inno Setup is still shaping up to be a heck of a lot more usable than WiX. Thanks.

Comment: Could be said so. It would be nice to have a new flag `backup` for `[InstallDelete]` section entries which would make a backup of the file(s) or folder(s) of that entry (probably pack all the files into a single archive) and which would also log this action to the uninstaller for rollback. Currently, there's no such option, but still there's a way to write something similar by yourself.

Comment: Surely the developers know what they've just removed, and you have a "base" setup template. Can't you just make sure that they also add the `[InstallDelete]` entry? The worst thing is that they forget and it gets left around until someone notices and adds it.

Comment: @Deanna I don't maintain a specific file list. The build happens automatically, and the installer just includes all the build output. This make adding or removing a file incredibly simple: the project output is the authoritative source, so you just output something while developing. I ended up just not supporting an in place upgrade.

Comment: But surely you know when you remove something?

Comment: @Deanna Possibly. Possibly not. For example, we depend on GDAL, which is quite a few files. What if we upgrade? Would we then have to figure out what files are no longer needed? It's also a hassle to remember to do extra things when there's no automatic verification that they've been done; someone is bound to forget sooner or later. Like if we remove a dependency. I wouldn't be thinking very much about the installer when I'm still in the middle of development, and I doubt many people would. Having to remember to do things is always a point of failure.